# Reshaping an Audio file array in python for Neural Network input

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am currently new to building neural networks with my own data set. I wanted to train a Convolutional Neural Network for audio classification but I am struggling with array reshaping.

I have first Recorded the audio on my phone and then loaded it using Librosa package to get a spectrogram output image array that I could use for my neural network.

```
sample = 2
filename = df.File[sample]
y, sr = librosa.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/AI Data Set/SoundRecord-2021-03-30-15-46-36.wav',sr=44100)
ps = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr) 
ps.shape. #Output (128,193)
```

And then I wanted to reshape it to (128,128), so I tried the following:

```
x = ps.reshape((128,128))
```

But It give me an error message: **ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 24704 into shape (128,128)**

And further more I have many such Audio files I got to reshape and then create a combined array and then reshape that array to (128,128,1) 3D array.

Please help me in this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your audio is too long. From librosa documentation, the output you get from melspectrogram method is the following:

```
S - np.ndarray [shape=(n_mels, t)]
```

`t` is the number of time bins which depends on the length of the input .wav file. You may truncate the input (`ps = ps[:,:128]`) or better (in your case) split melspectrogram into two overlapping ones

```py
melspecs = np.array([ps[:,:128], ps[:,-128:]])[..., np.newaxis]
```

In that case melspecs have the shape (2, 128, 128, 1) and thus can be feed to your network as a batch of size 2.
In order to infer the final classification you may vote the output the way you like.

Comment: Your solution has worked out. Can you also help me with one more thing, When I am trying to perform One-Hot encoding for classes :

`y_train = np.array(keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 4))`

`y_test = np.array(keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 4))`
I am getting an error message: IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

Comment: @AkellaNiranjan Sorry, I can't tell without knowing initial `y_train` shape.